# How to define a member function of a class at the class level or at the level of instance objects?

Tags: python, python-2.7

In Python 2.7, when defining a class, how can we define

- member functions at the level of class, i.e. its first argument is the class object, not an instance object of the class
- member functions at the level of the class' instance objects, i.e. its first argument is an instance object of the class, not the class object.

When using a given class, how can we tell if a member function is at the level of class or at the level of the class' instance objects?

For example, in the Python standard library, the `setUp()` from `TestCase` is called for each instance object of `TestCase`, i.e. at the level of instance objects, while 
class level fixtures are implemented in `TestSuite`. When the test suite encounters a test from a new class then `tearDownClass()` from the previous class (if there is one) is called, followed by `setUpClass()` from
the new class.

Thanks.

Comment: are you looking for @classmethod ?

Comment: Thanks. Maybe. Is `@classmethod` mentioned in some document at Python official website, when discussing classes and instance objects in general? I don't find `@classmethod` in the Python Language Reference, and the Python Tutorial.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod.  They are also mentioned in the very last paragraphs of this section - https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy . ... also check out the ```instance method``` heading of that link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The @classmethod form is a function decorator – see the description of
>   function definitions in Function definitions for details.
>
> It can be called either on the class (such as C.f()) or on an instance
>   (such as C().f()). The instance is ignored except for its class. If a
>   class method is called for a derived class, the derived class object
>   is passed as the implied first argument.
>
> Class methods are different than C++ or Java static methods. If you
>   want those, see staticmethod() in this section.
>
> For more information on class methods, consult the documentation on
>   the standard type hierarchy in The standard type hierarchy.

[https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#classmethod](http://DOCUMENT)

```
class A:
...    message = "class message"
... 
...    @classmethod
...    def classLevel(cls):
...       print(cls.message)
... 
...    def instanceLevel(self, msg):
...       self.message = msg
...       print(self.message)
>>> a= A()
>>> a.instanceLevel('123')
123
>>> A.classLevel()
class message
>>> a.classLevel()
class message
>>> A.instanceLevel()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unbound method instanceLevel() must be called with A instance as first argument (got nothing instead)


    A.__dict__
{'classLevel': <classmethod object at 0x4E974BB0>, '__module__': '__main__', 'instanceLevel': <function instanceLevel at 0x550C8530>, 'message': 'class message', '__doc__': None}
```